# How to conditionally route components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In one of my React project, I have to route to specific components but, it has same links and different paramaters. Go through the code for clarity.

Home.js

```
{/* It links to Video Component */}
<div>
<Link exact to={{ pathname: `/contents/lists/${videoId}`}} />
<span>
...video section code
<span>
</div>

{/* It links to Photo Component */}
<div>
<Link exact to={{ pathname: `/contents/lists/${photoId}`}} />
<span>
...photo section code
<span>
</div>
```

JSON data as

```
const data = {
  contents: {
    lists: {
      id: 5abcd,
      photo: {
        cover: "url"
      }
    },
    lists: {
      id: 5xyz,
      video: {
        cover: "url"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

App.js

```
<Route exact path="/contents/lists/:photoId" component={PhotosComp} />
<Route exact path="/contents/lists/:videoId" component={VideosComp} />
```

Here PhotosComp extracts the params id properly but, for VideosComp params id for PhotosComp is extracted and gives error, it doesn't link to VideosComp. What could be appropriate solution?

```
const item Data = [
{
text: Photo,
link: `/contents/lists/:photoId`
},{
text: Video,
link: `/contents/lists/:videoId`
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply choose different routes:

```
<Route exact path="/contents/photos/:photoId" component={PhotosComp} />
<Route exact path="/contents/videos/:videoId" component={VideosComp} />
```

and update your links:

```
<Link exact to={{ pathname: `/contents/videos/${videoId}`}} />
<Link exact to={{ pathname: `/contents/photos/${photoId}`}} />
```

In your current code, no body can understand if `/contents/lists/123456` should point to video component or the photo one.

Or if you must use same Route for some reason, then you can use some condition in your component:

```
<Route exact path="/contents/lists/:Id" component={MediaComp} />
```

And in MediaComp:

```
function MediaComp() {
    const id = ..... // todo
    if (some condition for video) 
      return <VideoComp/>
    else return <PhotoComp/>
}
```

Additionally, you can create links with some state data:

```
<Link exact to={{ pathname: `/contents/lists/${id}`, state: { type: 'photo' }}} />
```

And in MediaComp:

```
const type = history.location.state.type
if (type === 'photo) return <PhotoComp/> 
else..
```

Comment: Ya but, it needs to link accordingly JSON data as above

Comment: Ya right, but, api is like /contents/lists/123456 would point photo and /contents/lists/543211 would point to video

Comment: I was expecting something like this... Actually I have created a Middle component 'ContentAll' which routes as expected but, navigation isn't possible... I have also done this

Comment: This logic I have tried but, navigating between Videos and Photos is bit difficult

Comment: I don't understand when you say "navigation is difficult"

Comment: Thanks for the response, in my Navbar component links are created in object array like....please see above I've edited

Comment: Try with state data as I added in my answer.

Comment: OK I'll make changes in the component

Comment: Ya I'm able to route now but not navigate from Navbar component

Comment: Please either update your question or create a sandbox so that I can fully understand the issue.

Comment: Yes good idea, I forgot about sandbox... Please wait I'll create it,by the way thanks for your response